# How do I fix a make error for missing rule while building a Cyanogenmod image?

Tags: android, build, cyanogenmod

I am trying to build my own Cyanogenmod 11 image. I am using this link: [How To Build CyanogenMod Android for Samsung Galaxy Note 3 LTE ("hlte")](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Build_for_hlte#Prepare_the_device-specific_code)

And I get the following error message:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `vendor/samsung/hlte/proprietary/lib/cdma/libsec-ril.so', needed by `/root/android/system/out/target/product/hlte/system/lib/cdma/libsec-ril.so'.  Stop.
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
external/vim/src/spell.c: In function 'put_sugtime':
external/vim/src/spell.c:7869:12: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer     expressions [-Wsign-compare]
```

Let me know if you want me to post the make file. I can not imaging there not being a rule as this libsec-ril.so is related to the radio. Am I right?

Thanks to Dan, I found these errors when I try to pull files from my device, which runs the same version as I am trying to build i.e. Cyanogenmod 11. I posted a few of the other ones which adb pulled successfully also....

```
Extracting /system/vendor/lib/libmm-color-convertor.so ...
152 KB/s (9308 bytes in 0.059s)
Extracting /system/lib/cdma/libsec-ril.so ...
remote object '/system/lib/cdma/libsec-ril.so' does not exist
remote object '/system/lib/cdma/libsec-ril.so' does not exist
Extracting /system/lib/cdma/libril.so ...
remote object '/system/lib/cdma/libril.so' does not exist
remote object '/system/lib/cdma/libril.so' does not exist
Extracting /system/lib/gsm/libsec-ril.so ...
remote object '/system/lib/gsm/libsec-ril.so' does not exist
remote object '/system/lib/gsm/libsec-ril.so' does not exist
Extracting /system/lib/gsm/libril.so ...
remote object '/system/lib/gsm/libril.so' does not exist
remote object '/system/lib/gsm/libril.so' does not exist
Extracting /system/lib/libsensirion_h_2.so ...
673 KB/s (776792 bytes in 1.126s)
Extracting /system/lib/hw/sensors.msm8974.so ...
337 KB/s (62816 bytes in 0.181s)
Extracting /system/bin/ds_fmc_appd ...
402 KB/s (58776 bytes in 0.142s)
```

I found another post about the same question here: [Can't build Cyanogenmod](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2699509). The solution was to get the file from Git. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think you miss the proprietary blobs: `./extract-files.sh`

Comment: @shkschneider- Thanks. It is a little different. The rest of the directories seems to work. For some reason these files are not on the phone. I am posting them in the body of my original message. What can I do to fix it?